# openlayers map is not displayed in my app although it appears to be loaded without error

Tags: angular, openlayers

I followed some tutorial created in 2020 for displaying an openlayers map in an angular app and it is not working.
I dont get any error in the browser but the map appears to be loaded what i can see when introducing debug commands.
I put code here n stackblitz. Anybody got an idea why nothing is showing?

[my code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/vermilingua/oltest)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the styles for map in the map component.

Here is the updated version of your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-emqnol)

```
#map {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
```